# How to make JGraphX not duplicate nodes

Tags: java, jgraphx

Below is a simple example of the problem I am having. In my real data, I have many "links" coming from a data store that have the simple format of

```
entityA_ID, entityB_ID, Link_type
```

such as

```
a,b,"link"
a,c,"link"
b,d,"link"
```

so, the entityA_ID or entityB_ID field has "duplicates" because many things are linked to the same node.

How do I make the "World!" entity unique? 
This is what I see when I run it (actually an undirected graph would be fine):

[image]

and this is what I want, because I only want one World! entity (Excuse chicken scratch):

[image]

Here is the code

```
import com.mxgraph.layout.hierarchical.mxHierarchicalLayout;
import com.mxgraph.layout.mxGraphLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class HelloWorld1 extends JFrame {

  /**
   *
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2707712944901661771L;

  public HelloWorld1() {
    super("Hello, World!");

    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    mxGraphLayout layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    Set<String> inserted = new HashSet<>();
    try {


      Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Hello", 20, 20, 80, 30);
      Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150, 80, 30);
      Object v3 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150, 80, 30);
      graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
      graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge 2", v1, v3);
      graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge 3", v2, v3);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
      layout.execute(parent);
      graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);

    getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelloWorld1 frame = new HelloWorld1();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 320);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

this is my pom reference

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mxgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgraphx</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I doubt this can be managed at JGraphx level,  as it's giving you a "low level" interface to add the nodes.  Probably you could solve your issue by creating a "facade" where you keep a Map of the strings that have already been associated with a Node.  If you don't find the string in the map you'd create the node with "insertVertex". Otherwise,  you could return the node from the map. Is there any specific constraint that forces you to solve it at JGraphx level?

Comment: thanks @Insac I'll try that... no I don't have to force that logic upon jgraphx